# How to intercept and inspect notification transmitted in Android OS

Tags: android, encryption, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to intercept and log notification traffic of pinterest application. I've used burp suite and its certificate to intercept and log notification traffic. But it only shows HTTP protocol.
How can i intercept and log notification traffic of pinterest application? What protocol it is using ? if encrypted how to decrypt?

I'm guessing pinterest app uses firebase cloud message? Any tool to suggest?

[Screenshot of notification to be inspected and intercepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQy8u.png)

I've  tried using Burp Suite, PCAPdroid. Burp is not showing non-http protocol, PCAPdroid can not decrypt all protocol message. I want to see what protocol message coming with decrypted data.

Comment: If you ask for Accessibility privilege you can manage all notifications that appears on the phone (even about other Apps), but it's an additional privilege that the user have to explicit accept.